# Pact startup failed; tried calling service 60 times with no result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, web-api-testing

When I run the `npm run test:pact` I am getting the below error all the time.

> pact-core@11.1.1: Pact Binary Error: /Users/abc/Documents/Pega
> Docs/Code
> Bases/studiox-ui-service/packages/core/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/standalone/darwin-1.88.63/pact/lib/ruby/bin/ruby:
> line 14: Docs/Code: No such file or directory
>
> pact-core@11.1.1: Pact exited with code 1.
>
> Pact startup failed; tried calling service 60 times with no result.

- node version: 14.20.0
- npm version: 6.14.17
- `"@pact-foundation/pact": "10.0.0-beta.44",`

Comment: What is the content of the `test:pact` script in the `package.json` file?

Comment: @acdcjunior, `"test:pact": "jest --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --silent --runInBand --testPathPattern=test/contract"`